# How to edit .htaccess in order to display images above the web root?

Tags: .htaccess

I hope someone can help me out with this.
I am trying to display images on my site from a folder above my web root but without success so far. Images get uploaded to the folder but not showing up on the site.

Images in 
 /public_html/adpics

and my root directory
/public_html/mydomain.com

I have .htaccess files in /public_html/mydomain.com and /public_html/adpics

How can edit the .htaccess file to redirect the path to the image folder?

Thank you,
Jack

```
    RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                              

# Show ad                                                                                                                                     
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html        /index.php?view=showad&adid=$7&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Ads                                                                                                                                         
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/page([0-9]*)\.html            /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1&page=$7 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                   /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1 [QSA]

## Begin Version 5.2 - Pagination bug fix + Uniform page links ##

# Ads by cat                                                                                                                                  
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/page([0-9]*)\.html            /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=0&&cityid=$1&page=$5 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                                /index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]

## End Version 5.2 - Pagination bug fix + Uniform page links ##

# Show event                                                                                                                                  
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events(/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)))?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html         /index.php?view=showevent&date=$4&adid=$8&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Events on date                                                                                                                              
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))/page([0-9]*)\.html                /index.php?view=events&date=$3&cityid=$1&page=$7 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))                           /index.php?view=events&date=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events                                        /index.php?view=events&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Show image                                                                                                                                  
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                     /index.php?view=showimg&posterenc=$3&imgid=$4&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Images by user, paged                                                                                                                       
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/([^/]+)/page([0-9]+)\.html                         /index.php?view=imgs&posterenc=$3&cityid=$1&page=$4 [QSA]

# Top Images, paged                                                                                                                           
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/page([0-9]+)\.html                             /index.php?view=imgs&cityid=$1&page=$3 [QSA]

# Images by user                                                                                                                              
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images/([^/]+)                                    /index.php?view=imgs&posterenc=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Top Images                                                                                                                                  
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/images                                        /index.php?view=imgs&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# Quick ad/event/image                                                                                                                        
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/showpost/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                           /index.php?view=showad&adid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/showevent/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                          /index.php?view=showevent&adid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/showimage/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html                          /index.php?view=showimg&imgid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]

# City/Region                                                                                                                                 
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                                           /index.php?view=main&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                                           /index.php?view=main&cityid=$1 [QSA]

## Begin Version 5.0 ##

# RSS URLs
RewriteRule ^feed/posts                                                                             /rss.php?view=ads&cityid=0 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed/events                                                                            /rss.php?view=events&cityid=0 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed/([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?          /rss.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed/([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?                               /rss.php?view=ads&catid=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed/([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts                                                    /rss.php?view=ads&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed/([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events/(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))                      /rss.php?view=events&date=$3&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^feed/([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/events                                                   /rss.php?view=events&cityid=$1 [QSA]

## End Version 5.0 ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what exactly you mean, but looks like should be an easy task, since htacces can very easily `rewrite your urls` or `redirect` your users `temporary or permanent` and `above or below water`.

All I know about htaccess, I learned from the below link, it's worth checking out!

## [Guide to Stupid htaccess Tricks Worth Mastering](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/)

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for looking at my question. I am complete newbie when it comes to htaccess. How would I write this piece of code? http://www.mydomain.com/userimgs/image.jpg  My userimgs folder is above mydomain.com